# Conditional entropy for Markov chain

Tags: markov-process, information-theory

Say you have a Markov chain $X \to Y \to Z$, and you want to compute $H(Z | X)$. Other quantities, such as $H(Z)$, $H(Y)$, $H(Z | Y)$ and $H(Y | X)$, are relatively straight-forward to compute. Is there any way to get $H(Z | X)$ from these quantities?

Thanks :-)

Comment: As $P(Z|X)=\sum_y P(Z|Y)P(Y|X)$, the relation between $H(Z|X)$ and $H(Z|Y)$,$H(Y|X)$, ... is non-linear and I therefore don't see any straight-forward way to compute it from these quantities ...

Comment: I agree it doesn't seem easy to do it... But then maybe one can rephrase the question as, what do you need in order to be able to compute H(Z | X)?